# How to publish selfmade stream with ffmpeg and c++ to rtmp server?

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, rtmp, libavcodec, libavformat

Have a nice day to you, people!

I am writing an application for Windows that will capture the screen and send the stream to Wowza server by rtmp (for broadcasting). My application use ffmpeg and Qt.
I capture the screen with WinApi, convert a buffer to YUV444(because it's simplest) and encode frame as described at the file decoding_encoding.c (from FFmpeg examples):

```
///////////////////////////
//Encoder initialization
///////////////////////////
avcodec_register_all();
codec=avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
c = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
c->width=scr_width;
c->height=scr_height;
c->bit_rate = 400000;
int base_num=1;
int base_den=1;//for one frame per second
c->time_base= (AVRational){base_num,base_den};
c->gop_size = 10;
c->max_b_frames=1;
c->pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV444P;
av_opt_set(c->priv_data, "preset", "slow", 0);

frame = avcodec_alloc_frame();
frame->format = c->pix_fmt;
frame->width  = c->width;
frame->height = c->height;

for(int counter=0;counter<10;counter++)
{
///////////////////////////
//Capturing Screen
///////////////////////////
    GetCapScr(shotbuf,scr_width,scr_height);//result: shotbuf is filled by screendata from HBITMAP
///////////////////////////
//Convert buffer to YUV444 (standard formula)
//It's handmade function because of problems with prepare buffer to swscale from HBITMAP
///////////////////////////
    RGBtoYUV(shotbuf,frame->linesize,frame->data,scr_width,scr_height);//result in frame->data
///////////////////////////
//Encode Screenshot
///////////////////////////
    av_init_packet(&pkt);
    pkt.data = NULL;    // packet data will be allocated by the encoder
    pkt.size = 0;
    frame->pts = counter;
    avcodec_encode_video2(c, &pkt, frame, &got_output);
    if (got_output) 
    {
        //I think that  sending packet by rtmp  must be here!
        av_free_packet(&pkt);             

    }

}
// Get the delayed frames
for (int got_output = 1,i=0; got_output; i++)
{
    ret = avcodec_encode_video2(c, &pkt, NULL, &got_output);
    if (ret < 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error encoding frame\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        if (got_output)
        {
        //I think that  sending packet by rtmp  must be here!
        av_free_packet(&pkt);      
        }
}

///////////////////////////
//Deinitialize encoder
///////////////////////////
avcodec_close(c);
av_free(c);
av_freep(&frame->data[0]);
avcodec_free_frame(&frame);
```

I need to send video stream generated by this code to RTMP server.
In other words, I need c++/c analog for this command:

```
ffmpeg -re -i "sample.h264" -f flv rtmp://sample.url.com/screen/test_stream
```

It's useful, but I don't want to save stream to file, I want to use ffmpeg libraries for realtime encoding screen capture and sending encoded frames to RTMP server inside my own application.
Please give me a little example how to initialize AVFormatContext properly and to send my encoded video AVPackets to server.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

My problem can be solved by using example from the source of ffmpeg. File `muxing.c` is needed. It's located in the folder `ffmpeg\docs\examples` in the ffmpeg's sources. There are all needed source code for writing sample stream into a rtmp server or file. I must only understand those sources and add my own stream data instead of sample stream.
There could be unexpected problems, but in general - there is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same issue. When I push an RTMP stream using the FFmpeg command line, there is no problem.
However, when I use the C API to push the stream, the rtmp server cannot resolve the stream and always return "-32" which means "Broken pipe". The process of my code is as follows:

```
mp4 -> demuxing -> AVFrame -> muxing -> flv --- RTMP ---> RTMP server
```

It turns out that the core of this problem is that I did not set a separate header file for the flv stream.

Finally, it works.
Setting `AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER` to `AVFormatContext->flags` does not work. This results that `AVStream->codecpar->extradata` will be NULL. This actually causes pipe broken.
Setting `AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER` to `AVCodecContext->flags` solves the problem, but it should be executed before opening the encoder.

The key of the code like:

```
setting the AVCodecContext...

if (FormatContext->oformat->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER){
       AVCodecContext->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;
}

avcodec_open2(AVCodecContext, AVCodec, NULL);
```

The solution can also be found out in ffmpeg/doc/examples/muxing.c.

Overall, the problem appears when some output formats want stream headers to be separate and it can be solved by setting `AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER` to `AVCodecContext->flags`